# Moving data from MsSQL to Cosmos DB of FHIR server(open source version)

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I am using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer to move patient resource data from MsSQL to Azure cosmos DB of FHIR server. I have installed the FHIR server using the below github link.

https://github.com/Microsoft/fhir-server/blob/master/docs/DefaultDeployment.md

I am  able to move MsSQL server data inside FHIR cosmos db server but data format is not matching with FHIR server apps.

Example :- I have patient data with sql server side and we want to move all data with FHIR cosmos db ("resource type ":"Patient")and query on it. FHIR sever apps/services is not able to map with MsSQL  server data.

> Are there any Azure functions that can be run so that the  bulk
> ingestion of data into the FHIR server ?(Posting data with Postman is one way which is not feasible for bulk data)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vinayaka you are on a right track with Azure function.

In a nutshell, it is a simple post/put requests of FHIR resources from MS SQL into FHIR Server endpoints.

One approach could be a simple Azure function or a console app, that loops through FHIR json resources and post them in async way.

My humble advice: bump up capacity/throughput of FHIR server before running your ingestion process/load, and downgrade it as needed once ingestion of FHIR resources is completed.

You could also reuse [Microsoft FhirImporter function](https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server-samples/tree/master/src/FhirImporter) for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a Data Factory pipeline to load the data to CosmosDB in the correct format.  You may need to do some transformation to get the data into the format that FHIR expects.

Comment: Any idea regarding,  creating the Data Factory pipeline would be helpful.

Comment: ADF is an orchestration tool for data related transformation, it would still require an invoke of some servreless function or  endpoint to post FHIR resources.